# How to connect wordpress with amazonaws

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I am very curios how to connect wordpress website with amazon aws similar to following website.

s3.amazonaws.com/samsung-promo-code/samsung/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The example your giving is about hosting static files on Amazon S3 
See how you can configure a S3 bucket to serve HTTPs request https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

S3 is storing objects, it does not execute code. 
Wordpress is not made of static pages, it is written in PHP and requires an execution environment to execute.

To install wordpress on AWS, you need to start EC2 instances (virtual machines) and install wordpress on these virtual machines.
Have a look at this documentation to get started :
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/